Scale is off when using EPSG:32616 (WGS 84 / UTM Zone 16N)
I am working on a project in QGIS where I have projected all data in EPSG:32616 to fit the extent I am mapping (Southern Mexico - chat gpt told me to use this crs). Everything looks visually correct but the scale is way off in both the main QGIS window and the print layoung. I am displaying several regions in Mexico and QGIS tells me that the scale is 1:15.
I have tried restarting the programme, downloading the newest long term release of QGIS and double checking that the project and all data are in the same CRS (which they are). This is the extent that I want to display, more or less. .

And this is what my scalebar looks like in the print layout.
Finally, it looks like this in the main QGIS window:

Am I using the wrong projection for this area?
Here are the scalebar properties in the layout:

Here is the information of some of my layers in a blank project:


You can check the suitable CRS on EPSG.io or look at what the local geo-spatial scientists use. EPSG:32616 seems to be using meters, which should not be an issue. Can you make a screenshot of your scalebar settings?

How did you project the data to EPSG:32616?

your coordinates are in decimal degrees, UTM are in meters. What is the Coordinate reference system of the project? What are the parameter for the scale bar in the print layout?

@ChloeG Thanks. I added a screenshot of the scalebar properties, let me know if this is what you meant :)

@user2856  I first changed the projection in each layer's properties and then I used the 'reproject' tool. The reason I changed it in the properties first was that when I tried only using the tool they ended up in different locations.. maybe I should have only used the tool instead for all layers? :)

@GerardoJimenez yes I was confused by this too.. the CRS is EPSG:32616 (WGS 84 / UTM Zone 16N)... I added a screenshot of the scalebar properties, let me know if this is what you mean by the parameter :)

Remove and re-add the original layers. Leave the layers properties CRS definitions alone and change the project properties CRS definition to UTM. If the layers CRS definitions are correct to begin with, QGIS will automatically reproject them on the fly to match the project CRS.

@user2856 I know that it does not change the data's CRS, which is why I reprojected them using the tool. Should I not have done that? Is removing and re-adding them the only way to  fix it? The issue is that I have created new layers and made selections from the original layers and saved them with the CRS mentioned above. If possible I do not want to start from scratch cause I only have a limited amount of time I can spend on this project...

@user2856 to clarify, i changed the project'S CRS before changing the layers.

Can you open a blank project, add the original layers and open the layers properties -> Information tab and copy the extent and original CRS properties and edit your question to include that info, e.g. https://i.sstatic.net/IYfYHyLW.png

@user2856 yes I will do this! Unfortunately I forgot my computer and will not have it until Wednesday but I will do it then! Thanks for the assistance

@user2856 I added a screenshot of one of the first layers I added.

Looks to me like those layers haven't been reprojected, just had the CRS definition changed as your 3rd image has WGS84 coordinates but EPSG:32616 definition.  Try changing the layer CRS definition back to WGS84 (EPSG:4326).  You shouldn't generally need to reproject layers for viewing/mapping as QGIS will reproject them on the fly to match the map canvas/project CRS.
